# After fixing a doctype declaration, my page broke

Tags: html, css, doctype

So. I have this really weird problem. I'm constructing about three websites simultaneously but I've been copy+pasting the base code to save time. I didn't realize that my doctype declaration was misspelled. I had it as `<!doctype HMTL>` which is obviously spelled incorrectly, but all of my pages were operating as the CSS told them to. When I realized I'd misspelled, I tried to correct the error but then some spacing and border functions weren't working properly. Is there a particular reason for this? For instance

```
html, body {
  min-height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

Produces a 0px margin, but doesn't extend the body which is a problem because there's a border on it. If I go back to the misspelled version of the doctype declaration, will that have some negative side effects on other browsers?

Also, I'm using Adobe EdgeCode and my test environment is in Chrome.

Comment: if you have a misspelled doctype, your rendering will be so-called quirksmode rendering. With a proper doctype you'll have standards compliant rendering. The recommended way is to have standard compliant rendering *and* your css issues fixed. However, there are a *lot* of sites with quirksmode rendering, so it can certainly work as well - you'll just have to be even more careful not to break anything.

Comment: The title is misleading. Because you misspelled the document type, your page was already broke. As a consequence, Chrome kicked into quirks mode and you were programming based on that. If you correct the spelling, you will go into standards mode and be playing on a level playing field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `height:100%` to your `html`.

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. [MDN - min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

Like this:

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
html, body{
   min-height:100%;
   margin:0; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLa2hkqz/)